# What do each of the element & status symbols mean?

Tags: final-fantasy-12

When I use Libra, I can see icons depicting those elements against which the enemy is weak. But some of the symbols are so abstract that I can't figure out their meaning: A "Skull Defender" is weak against a white circle:

[image]

But what does "white circle" mean? Is there a guide somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like the [Holy](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Holy_(element)#Final_Fantasy_XII) element to me.

Regarding the other part of your question, the following is a list of status effects in FFXII:

- [image] X-Zone
- [image] K.O.
- [image] Stone
- [image] Doom
- [image] Petrify
  <sub>**Note:** For Doom and Petrify, a countdown (4.5 seconds per tick) starting from 10 will appear by the health bar above the unit. The character will be KO'd/turned to stone when the count reaches 0.</sub>
- [image] Slow
- [image] Stop
- [image] Haste
- [image] Confuse
- [image] Sleep
- [image] Disease
- [image] Reverse
- [image] Disable
- [image] Immobilize
- [image] Silence
- [image] Blind
- [image] Poison
- [image] Oil
- [image] Sap
- [image] Regen
- [image] Bubble
- [image] Lure
- [image] Reflect
- [image] Protect
- [image] Shell
- [image] Bravery
- [image] Faith
- [image] Invisible
- [image] Float
- [image] Berserk
- [image] Libra

For more information about status effects, see [here](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XII_statuses).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! And I see that each element icon is likewise shown at the top-right of each section of https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XII_elements .

Comment: how long did this answer take you? copy pasting the icons is super helpful :D

Comment: @nightsurfer too much xD but Arqade doesn't like "link-only answers", so I had to

Comment: While you linked the Wiki, it might be worth adding a note that the subscript text "10" for Doom and Petrify is a countdown timer that will inflict K.O and Stone respectively when the timer reaches 0